# How to use a single default catch in a double returned promise?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Basically I have a construction like;

```
// Library function
function foo(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  // Do lots of stuff, like rendering a prompt

  // On user action
  if(userDidSomething){
    resolve(user_input);
  }

  if(userCanceled){
     // On user cancel
     reject('User canceled');
  }
  }).catch("Default error (usually canceling whatever it is, which means; do nothing)");
}

// Function to call library function with predefined settings for this website
function bar(){
 // Have some defaults set here, like which kind of prompt it should be 
 return foo();
}

// Where the function will actually be used
function baz(){
 bar().then("do some things");
}
```

I've worked my way around this issue some years ago but unfortunately forgot how I actually managed to do that.

**The goal:** Have one standard `catch` handle things for me on the library level. If I want to overrule it, I can always do that later. So I guess it's: Break the chain.

**The problem:** Having the `catch` before the `then`, causes the `then` to be triggered once I have dealt with the `catch` (which is; ignoring it, in this case)

**My current solution:** I'm using `throw` on the library-level `catch`, this causes the promise to throw an `uncaught error exception`.
However, this completely clutters up my console with errors which aren't really errors.

The problem is that the entire `resolve`/`reject` of the promise is being handled by the library. That promise gets returned around and I only call it way later.

This is a function I'm calling about 300 times throughout my project, and I don't want to be putting custom error handling on every single one of those function calls when the handling of this should be "don't do anything, really".

Comment: *Having the catch before the then, causes the then to be triggered once I have dealt with the catch (which is; ignoring it, in this case)* - this is not true, order doesn't matter here

Comment: Order does matter in a Promise. Once I let the catch end, it continues up the chain with the next .then(), as the catch was resolved. If I do `return "hello world!"` in my catch, my `.then(r => alert(r))` will say "Hello world!". That's kind of the whole issue.

Comment: You are calling both `resolve` and `reject` you should call only one.

Comment: no, I'm not calling any resolve. I'll clarify my question

Comment: You are right, I was wrong

Comment: I wonder what should happen with the promise in your goal. A promise can be either `fulfilled`, `rejected` or `pending`, no other state to choose from.

Comment: So you basically want to return a promise, that, when rejected: 1. doesn't call `.then`s, 2. doesn't print the error to the console. Right?

Comment: @FZs Correct! Although a custom error like "canceled" would do, but now it throws an uncaught exception because I do a `throw` to break the chain. And if I do handle it without an uncaught exception, it resolves back into the `then` at the end of the chain.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, and I want it to get the status rejected, as keeping it on pending slowly eats RAM. Especially in an often recurring situation. As my question states, the problem is that once I reject it, but the chain is `catch().then()` instead of `then().catch()`, it continues into the 'then' after the catch. Handling the catch properly, turns the rejection into a resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not really possible using native Promises because that's not how they were intended to be used.

You can, though, create a custom Promise class that does this. Note that muting all rejections is a *bad idea* because you won't see if your code errors out. To go around that, only a special value (`SpecialPromise.CANCELED`) is treated differently. The code has to track whether a `.catch` is attached to it. When the promise encounters the special value *and* it has no catch callback at the moment, it quickly attaches a no-op catch callback to silence the error:

```
class SilentPromise extends Promise{
    constructor(executor){
        super((resolve, reject) => {
            executor(
                resolve, 
                e => {
                    if(e === this.constructor.CANCELED && !this._hasCatch){
                        this.catch(() => {})
                    }
                    reject(e)
                }
            )
        })
        this._hasCatch = false
    }
    then(success, error){
        this._hasCatch = true
        return super.then(success, error)
    }
    catch(error){
        this._hasCatch = true
        return super.catch(error)
    }
    catchIfNotCanceled(error){
        this.catch(e => {
            if(e === this.constructor.CANCELED)
                throw e
            return error(e)
        })
    }
}

SilentPromise[Symbol.species] = SilentPromise
SilentPromise.CANCELED = Symbol('CANCELED')
```

You can convert existing promises between `SilentPromise` and `Promise` using `SilentPromise.resolve()` and `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: Hmm I want to try this ASAP. A silent promise is a great idea! What you're saying about the errors is definitely true, but this is specifically about canceling a row of prompts, which should yield no errors as the handling is "do nothing". I would only use this there.

Anyway, what is the `Symbol` thing, exactly? I'm a bit confused about that one. I must admit to being a little confused about the use.

Comment: @NoobishPro Well, a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) is just a unique value. It is a normal JavaScript value that can be stored in variables and passed around like a number or a string, but similarly to how objects work, every call to `Symbol()` will return a new and unique symbol. They can also be keys in objects.

Comment: @NoobishPro The [`Symbol.species`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) line just makes chaining the  `SilentPromise` class return other SilentPromises, not normal Promises. The next line creates the `SilentPromise.CANCELLED` value, and if you throw that in a SilentPromise, it will be silent.

Comment: Thank you, this is *exactly* what I needed! I can just call or use promises exactly as intended, but on the few exceptions (user cancel/hiding of the active elements popping up) I can just silently kill the process including the promise. I can switch any promise to this depending on the rejection type (it being cancelled) after the fact. It's absolutely perfect. I still don't fully understand it as much as I'd like (the species thing), but it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @NoobishPro You're welcome :)  Setting a constructor's `Symbol.species` property specifies what constuctor that class' instance methods *should* use to create other instances (they don't have to, but all built-in types do use it). That is, setting it to `SilentPromise` is what made `SilentPromise.then()`, `SilentPromise.catch()`, etc. return other SilentPromises, not ordinary Promises (note that it's still `Promise.then` that's creating the new instance - SilentPromise call it with `super.then`).